# I want to make blogger H2,H3,H4 background confined to text size

Tags: css, blogger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/873dr.png)I use blogger and I have CSS for H2,3,4 tags with special background and text size.
I want the background size to fit the text size automatically and not to be the whole width of the page.

Can anyone help me with another code or css trick to make it work?

I replaced "display: block;" with "display: inline-block" and it worked but with problems as shown on image no. 2.

```
.post-body h3,.post-body h2,.post-body h4{background-color:#333333;width: auto;padding:10px 20px;color:#FFF;display: block;margin:5px 0 15px;border-bottom:1px solid $(post.line)}
```

[image: xxx]

[image: xxxx]

Comment: Is the following text wrapped in `<p>` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If heading element comes inside a text or between inline elements, you can use `display: table`

```css
h2 {
  display: table;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>


<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the h1 tags to `inline-block` it will behave like an inline element. That means if the following element is also online, they will just be displayed beside each other.

You can use `inline-block` on the header tags but make sure the following content is `display: block`. That will start the element in a new line and this way you can achieve what you want with the header tags.

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #FFF;
}

p {
  display: block; /* this is actually the default display for p tags*/
}
```

```html
<h1>lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga velit nulla molestiae sunt unde sint, neque optio, beatae cumque perspiciatis a quae eum omnis nesciunt minus veritatis nemo iusto soluta.</p>
```